# Заставить работать плагин в проекте cordova + angular

Tags: android, angular, плагин, cordova, android-webview

Я установил в этот проект плагины cordova-plugin-device, чтобы получить информацию об устройстве и т. д. И установил cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine, чтобы заработали другие плагины, т. к. нужно, чтобы проект работал через веб доступ, то есть в cordova просто транслируется сайт с другого сервера. Я объявил в одном из компонентов переменную для вывода uuid устройства таким образом:

```
declare let device: any;
```

и вывел на экран таким образом:

```
try {
    this.errorLog.nativeElement.innerHTML = device?.uuid;
  } catch( err ) {
    this.errorLog.nativeElement.innerHTML = err;
  }
```

И вот, если контент сайта транслируется через cordova, то выводится ошибка, а если я заливаю в cordova проект в папку www весь скомпилированный angular проект, то uuid устройсва отображается. Можно ли выполнить эту задачу в первом варианте, когда сайт транслируется в cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя несколько дней нашел решение этой задачи. Нужно добавить в проект cordova такой плагин:

**cordova-plugin-remote-injection** - важный плагин, без него не заработают остальные плагины (если открываете контент через веб доступ)